# JDBC - Configure white-spaces from 'char' datatype

Tags: jdbc, char, whitespace, informix, sqldatatypes

How can JDBC be configured to automatically trim white-spaces coming from a column where the data type is defined as a `char(20)`?

When a column has a char(xx) defined in a table of an Informix database, each of those reserved characters will be filled with white-spaces if not used.

**Ex.:** Column name *prefix* of type `char(20)` with a value of "test" will ultimately be read as:

```
"test                " <- 4 characters + 16 white-spaces
```

Is there a configuration file which can handle white-spaces from these types of database fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use IFX_TRIMTRAILINGSPACES in your connection string:

```
D:\Infx\work\Java>cat select.java

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class select {
 public static void main( String [] args ) {

 Connection conn = null;
 ResultSet dbRes = null;
 Statement is = null;

 try {
    Class.forName("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver");

   conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:informix-sqli://420ito:9088/stores7:INFORMIXSERVER=ids1210;user=informix;password=dummy;IFX_TRIMTRAILINGSPACES=0");

    is = conn.createStatement();

        is.executeUpdate("drop table t22;create table t22(c1 char(20))");
        is.executeUpdate("insert into t22 values ('abc        ')");
    PreparedStatement pstmt=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT *  from  t22");
    dbRes= pstmt.executeQuery();
    while (dbRes.next()) {
      System.out.format("--%s--,",dbRes.getString(1));
          try {
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {};
    }
    dbRes.close();
    conn.close();
  }
  catch ( Exception e ) {
    System.err.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
}


D:\Infx\work\Java>javac select.java

D:\Infx\work\Java>java select
--abc                 --,
D:\Infx\work\Java>grep TRIM select.java
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:informix-sqli://420ito:9088/stores7:INFORMIXSERVER=ids1210;user=informix;password=dummy;IFX_TRIMTRAILINGSPACES=1");

D:\Infx\work\Java>javac select.java

D:\Infx\work\Java>java select
--abc--,
D:\Infx\work\Java>
```

from the manual:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/ids_jdbc_040.htm